# How to use getJson to send variable to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Here is the javascript code that has a "no" in the datastring and i want to pass that datastring to data.php using getJson So that in the end i can get json as a response. My data.php code is working but javascript code is not working so please help me.

Javascript code

```
dataString = 'no='+ no; 

$.getJSON("data.php", dataString,function(response){

        console.log(response);
  });
```

php code

```
$no=$_POST['no'];

$headers = array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
);

$url = 'https://www.outpan.com/api/get-product.php?barcode='.$no.'&apikey=318c91a99b132a29dda536d63e7fb8b4';


$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);




 $result = curl_exec($ch);



curl_close($ch);

//$result_arr = json_decode($result, true);

echo result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is response is not valid JSON (I am not sure, since you seemed to have tried printing the `json_decoded version`).
Try printing out the error by using `error` which is called when no valid JSON is received -

```
$.getJSON("data.php", dataString,function(response){
    console.log(response)
}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
    console.log(textStatus+" - "+errorThrown); 
});
```

If an error is logged, then checkout the curl response in php and make sure it is valid json.

**EDIT**

This edit is assuming that he php response is invalid JSON as observed from the comments. 
Looking at your php code, you have used this -

```
$headers = array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
);
```

Try this instead -

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

**EDIT 2**
Looking at your php code again, there seems to be an error while printing -

```
echo result;
```

It should be -

```
echo $result;
```

Comment: This is the error "parsererror - SyntaxError: Unexpected token a"

Comment: @AbdurRehmanFarooqi Yep, thats it. The PHP response is invalid json.

Comment: now i have commented the json part and just echo a statement and it is not returned as response.

Comment: @AbdurRehmanFarooqi before you print anything, just [copy paste the contents here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and check if it is valid JSON.

Comment: Its not working if is send you source code can you make the changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80080/discussion-between-abdur-rehman-farooqi-and-kamehameha).

Answer (score 0):

use $_GET In your php code, you are using $_POST now

Comment: i have checked it. Its not working. i think there is a problem with getjson

Answer (score 0):

You should $_GET in your php code or change code like this :

```
$.getJSON("data.php", { no: no },function(response){

    console.log(response);
  });
```

In php use,

```
$no=$_REQUEST['no'];
```